# Routing specific server traffic through my VPS

Tags: proxy, dante

I've got a "multihome" setup: 2 internet connections, which boosts my speed significantly.

I've set up a proxy on my VPS for regular browsing, but some applications don't support this, and they don't like 2 IPs accessing their server with the same credentials, for example: usenet servers.

So I was wondering: how can I setup a specific port on my VPS as a proxy for another server?

I've tried it with Dante, like this:

```
pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: usenet-server.com port = 563
protocol: tcp udp
```

But that did not work...

Answer (score 2):

An ssh -L tunnel might solve the problem, as long as the server connected to stays the same and tcp is used.

Comment: True, but if I'm not mistaken that would always use the same connection, so it'll only use 1 of the 2 internet connections.

Comment: It will take whatever path to the VPS your normal IP routing will send you to, but from the view of the target server you are connecting from the VPS. Or did I misunderstand your Setup? I assumed "2 local internet connections, one remote VPS that has one static address".